# CakePHP how to combine process steps

Tags: cakephp, button

I am developing a system that allows users to download files, but IF they download a file I want to log this action in a special purpose table (MySQL).

I can already generate an icon with a link to appropriate file, but I can't see how I can make the record of the click on the icon to download the file also create the log record.

I am guessing I will have to use a button, and set the action of the button to run ... what? a controller action, a helper function, something else...

It is the last bit that I can't really get my head round.  I would appreciate any advice from anyone who may have implemented something similar!

bw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Link to a controller action, which will write to the database & log, and will load the file and present it to the user.

Example:

```
class MyController extends AppController {

    // Load the model
    public $uses = ('DbTable');

    public function get_file() {
        // Save the DB record
        $this->DbTable->save(...);

        // Set the output header for content delivery 
        // (use the appropriate mime-type for your file)
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

        // Have it download as if it were an attachment
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"');

        // Print out the file contents
        echo file_get_contents('/path/to/filename.jpg');

        // Prevent any further processing or rendering
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks Steven.  I am using cakephp 2.2 - is the above all supported?

Comment: Yeah, should be, although it's not a complete snippet of code... you'll have to modify it to suit your exact needs (e.g. the `Model->save()` bit).

Comment: Hi - sorry for being thick.. You suggested I link to the controller action - so I am trying to use html->link - however, I need to pass an array of parameters to the controller action, as the controller is not the same controller as the one used by the linking view.. I can't seem to get that to work.  Any ideas, or should I open up another question?

Comment: Try `<a href="/controller_name/action_name/">Download File</a>`

Comment: Hi Steve, I am having problems with function calls between models/controllers.  I think I had better open a new question.  I will come back here to tick your answer once I have got the other part to work.  The writing to the table log is working well! Just the download bit to test (once I have this function sorted!)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have been told how to make my cross model functions work, and putting that into  your suggested solution means that it all works beautifully.  Thanks again for your help.